# How to use RhoElements features (call Rho API's) in Sencha Touch application (javascript file)

Tags: sencha-touch-2, rhomobile

I am in a process of developing a mobile app using Sencha Touch 2 (for UI) packaged with RhoElements.
How to access the Rho features in Sencha Touch UI (Java script files). For example if I want to use the scanner/camera feature from Rho in the UI, how is that done? Is there a code sample for that?

Looking at the RhoElements sample application, all the scanner/camera calls are made in Ruby controllers. So not sure how to tie them both?

Comment: as far as I first time hear about Rho, I'd suggest to you specify, what exactly markup you want to get as an output. Then I will show you how to create a Sencha component for this.

Answer (score 0):

I do both Rho and Sencha.  There are many example on the RhoMobile site that walks you thru the integration.

Answer (score 0):

here is the documentation of the API reference for JS client. Also there are some examples

[Rhomobile](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhoconnectjs/reference)